# Asignar los valores de las EMA que genere a cada fila del archivo xts de GBPUSD en una columna nueva. Codigo R. Como hago?

Tags: r

```
library(quantmod)


getSymbols('GBPUSD', src ="av", api.key='', periodicity='intraday', interval = '15min', output.size = 'full')

chartSeries(GBPUSD, TA = NULL, theme = 'white', subset = 'last 2 day')
addEMA(n = 50, wilder = FALSE, ratio=NULL, on = 1, with.col = Cl, overlay = TRUE, col = "blue")
addEMA(n = 200, wilder = FALSE, ratio=NULL, on = 1, with.col = Cl, overlay = TRUE, col = "red")
```

Comment: Bienvenido Damian Izcovich a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Answer (score 0):

El problema principal que los EMA que incorporas a tu gráfica son objetos que no contienen las medias móviles de cada observación, sino que se calculan al vuelo a la hora de gráficarlos. Si tienen, imagino yo los valores significativos que luego se usan para dibujar la curva, veamos uno te tus ejemplos:

```
m1 <- addEMA(n = 50, wilder = FALSE, ratio=NULL, on = 1, with.col = Cl, overlay = TRUE, col = "blue")
length(GBPUSD$GBPUSD.Open)
[1] 975

length(m1@TA.values)
[1] 164
```

Asignamos la salida de `addEMA()` a un variable `m1` y chequeamos los valores de `m1@TA.values`, que parecen ser los que se usan para construir la curva, al menos un simple `plot(m1@TA.values)` nos muestra una curva bastante similar a la del gráfico original:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Teniendo estos valores podemos "interpolarlos", usando la función base de R: [`spline()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/splinefun) y así generar las observaciones que nos faltan:

```
puntos <- c(rep(NA, 50), spline(1:length(m1@TA.values), m1@TA.values, n=length(GBPUSD$GBPUSD.Close)-50)$y)
GBPUSD$m1 <- puntos
tail(GBPUSD)

                    GBPUSD.Open GBPUSD.High GBPUSD.Low GBPUSD.Close GBPUSD.Volume       m1
2020-11-27 15:30:00      1.3303      1.3305     1.3300       1.3304             0 1.332274
2020-11-27 15:45:00      1.3304      1.3305     1.3301       1.3303             0 1.332259
2020-11-27 16:00:00      1.3304      1.3307     1.3291       1.3295             0 1.332244
2020-11-27 16:15:00      1.3294      1.3304     1.3285       1.3299             0 1.332230
2020-11-27 16:30:00      1.3300      1.3302     1.3297       1.3301             0 1.332216
2020-11-27 16:45:00      1.3300      1.3305     1.3298       1.3302             0 1.332202
```

Nota: el valor `n` de `addEMA()` establece la ventana de calculo, con `n=50`, la media se va calculando con ventanas de 50 observaciones, esto hay que ajustarlo en la generación de los puntos, como vemos en el código anterior, para una ventana de `n=50`.

No sé que tan bueno para tu análisis puede ser este método, pero creo que lo más práctico antes de tener que construir una función de media móvil exponencial que genere todas las observaciones.

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio!